# PHP: Find values in array with preg_grep without case sensitive

Tags: php, regex

I have an array and I want to find values in it like in sql "LIKE".
This works fine, but it is case sensitive.

```
$result = preg_grep('~' . $string . '~', $fileArray);
```

The Regex for caseSensitive is "i", but I don't make it work. Sorry I'm really new in Regex, but I think this is so simple, but I dont get it... Can someone please help me with this?
Tried this, but doesn't work.

```
$result = preg_grep('~\i' . $string . '~', $fileArray);
$result = preg_grep('~*\i' . $string . '~', $fileArray);
```

Comment: `$result = preg_grep('~' . $string . '~i', $fileArray);`

Comment: `$result = preg_grep('~' . $string . '~i', $fileArray);`

Comment: @Phylogenesis omg in the same second the same text :D almost worth a screenshot

Comment: Oh no, I know that it was simple! THANK YOU VERY MUCH! Had it on the wrong position.

Comment: @Rizier123: definetly worth! http://prntscr.com/5mjt87

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the regex modifier after the delimiters like this:

```
$result = preg_grep('~' . $string . '~i', $fileArray);
                                   //^^See here the Modifier
                                   //|Here the delimiter
```

Also good to know:

[Regex Cheat Sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)
[Test your Regex](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I would also recommend using `preg_quote()`.